# Como usar el mismo FORM para un GET y un POST

Tags: html, python, url

mi pregunta es como puedo usar un mismo FORM en HTML para hacer un GET o un POST. En este caso estoy haciendo un login, pero quiero usar el input Nombre tanto para el login como para el registro. Os dejo el codigo:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <form class="" action="{{ url_for('login') }}" method="GET">
            <h1>Sign in</h1>
            <input type=text name="name" placeholder="Name">
            <button>Sign in</button>
            <button>Register</button> --Si doy click en este botón quiero hacer un POST al servidor
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Server

```
@app.route('/homepage', methods=['GET','POST'])
def login():
    #Compruebo el método
    if request.method == 'GET': 
        name = request.args.get('name')
        user = mongo.db.users.find_one({'name': name})
        return render_template("homepage.html", connections = user['conn'])
    else:
        name = request.json['name']
        #Si no se encuentra en la base de datos (aseguramos que sea unico)
        if (not mongo.db.users.find_one({"name": name})):
            id = mongo.db.users.insert_one({
                'name': name,
                'conn': [
                ]
            })
            print(id)
            return("post")
        #Si lo hemos encontrado
        else:
            return "encontrado"
```

Como se ve el método login() recoge tanto GET como POST. En el caso de GET hago el login y redirigo a la página principal del usuario, pero en caso de ser una consulta POST, primero compruebo si el usuario ya existe (si existe mando un mensaje de error, pero todavía no esta modelado), y en caso de que no exista, lo añado a la base de datos y, posteriormente, redirigo a su página de inicio

Comment: Da gusto ver un `python` correctamente formateado ... pero creo que se te pasó un *detallito* ... ¿ Cual es el problema o pregunta ? Un saludo.

Comment: El form que contiene los botones está usando el metodo GET, pero para hacer un registro tengo que hacer una petición POST. Mi pregunta es: ¿cómo puedo usar el mismo form para hacer tanto peticiones get como post?